# Tap an ImageView and open a TableViewController

Tags: swift, uiimage, tableview, swift5

So, I am new to Swift and Xcode and I’m still trying to figure out how to do the next thing:
I want to put more images in a ViewController and when I press one image, a table view should open. How Am I supposed to do that? I’m working in Swift 5.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried. Tell us what you have researched.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ***UITapGestureRecognizer***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

@objc func imageTapped() {
    //perform segue to your tableview controller
}
```